# Error while creating URL. URL string is working fine in browser

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm trying the following code to create a URL:

**Approach 1:**

```
let url = URL (string: "https://xxxx-xxxx.com/xxx.html?tokenID=PuUPbFjauRZNPrHQot3Xea70loblCZL3GP9HOrjDP7vTvP3ROWDZrmFJlvKBC1oQ&MobileKey=DE1C-7B19-9CFC83CB83C8||Apple,simulator&widvalue=cl-mobile-dashboard")
let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!) // <<== error here!
```

However I'm getting the error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

**Approach 2:**

```
var _request : URLRequest?
if let webViewURL = URL(string: "https://xxxx-xxxx.com/xxx.html?tokenID=PuUPbFjauRZNPrHQot3Xea70loblCZL3GP9HOrjDP7vTvP3ROWDZrmFJlvKBC1oQ&MobileKey=DE1C-7B19-9CFC83CB83C8||Apple,simulator&widvalue=cl-mobile-dashboard") {
    _request = URLRequest(url:webViewURL) // <<== execution not entering this block!!
}
```

Can anybody please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash exactly? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Test the value of the `url` variable instead of using `!` to insist that it's non-nil.

Comment: Updated code above with second approach where I'm not forcefully unwrapping.. using optional safely. Can you please help.

Comment: Is the url the one you are using there? For me it works fine.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that `UIWebView` has been deprecated in favour of `WKWebView`.

Comment: Clearly you are not really using the exact URL posted in your question. Whatever URL you are really using isn't valid. Post the actual URL (but with a fake domain name if desired) you are really using. You probably have one or more characters than need to be escaped properly.

Comment: How are you building that URL? Show that code. Or are you hardcoding that whole string in your code?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm constructing that url based on tokenID from backend and UDID as well as other parameters from a cipher text. I'm just appending all these together. funny part is, it works as if I'm transacting with this device even when I paste it in a web browser on my Mac. Thats why I'm kinda frustrated debugging this. Can you please help me.